# Automated Deployment Options

Tags: .net, asp.net, deployment, msbuild

We have a web application primarily developed in .NET and are entering into an era where we will be deploying the application at client owned windows infrastructure. 
Our goal is to complete deployment of the application in less than 15 minutes including
* Deployment across at least 8 or more web server instances
* Creating a backup of the existing deployment to support rollback
* Updating configuration files on each server with server specific properties
... 
all the typical tasks that would come with a departmental application

In my prior world of Java applications, ANT did all of these. However, I am unable to find a tool that will do these for .NET based application - or atleast I am unhappy with the options

NANT hasnt seen much in terms of upgrades in the last year
MSBuild isnt as feature rich to accomplish something like this (or is it ?)
..
Looking for some pointers to tools that are widely used in the market today